# How can i use a minimum length of the sequence in cSPADE using R programming

Tags: r, pattern-matching, analytics, sequential

Assuming my output of the cSPADE would be similar to the following, How can i prevent the single nodes. As i am more concern in getting the pattern among two or more elements. Is there anyway i can put a **minimum length** ?

```
          sequence support
1            <{A}>    1.00
2            <{B}>    1.00
3            <{D}>    0.50
4            <{F}>    1.00
**5          <{A,F}>    0.75
6          <{B,F}>    1.00
7        <{D},{F}>    0.50
8      <{D},{B,F}>    0.50**
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package `arulesSequences`, but the [reference manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesSequences/arulesSequences.pdf) mentions `mingap` argument to `SPparameter` class. Is this something you would be after?

Comment: Well mingap is something which constraint the timestamp. I am looking for something which can restrict a minimum length of the sequence.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to share an answer I came up with after personally failing to find much help on this topic, in case any one else stumbles on this.

I failed to find an option in cspade directly that would allow for these sequences to not be outputted from the start, but you can eliminate them after the fact.

What you can do is use the function size() in the arulesSequences package. See ?size for additional details, but assuming you saved the cspade output as "seq", you can subset your cspade output like so:

```
myupdatedseq<-seq[size(seq,"itemsets")>1]
```

or equivalently,

```
myupdatedseq<-subset(seq, subset = size(x,"itemsets")>1)
```

See ?subset as well in the arulesSequences package for additional help subsetting sequences.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

```
myupdatedseq <- subset(seq, size(x) > 1)
```

or, if you want to convert to a data frame:

```
as(subset(seq, size(x) > 1), "data.frame")
```